# Count cells with or without image in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Google Spreadsheets supports an [`IMAGE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093333) function to include a graphic inside a cell. If the URL provided does not yield a valid picture resource, e.g. the server returns a `404` response, the cell will look empty and not throw any `#` error. Alas, neither of [`COUNT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093620), [`COUNTA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093991), [`COUNTBLANK`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093403) and [`COUNTUNIQUE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093405) treats these visually empty cells any different than those that successfully show an image (and neither do the respective [`IS...`](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273) functions). There also seems to be no respective expression that one could supply as a second parameter to [`COUNTIF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480)[(`S`)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550).

Is there any way to count all cells of a region that either contain or do not contain an image? If not, should this be considered a bug and be reported accordingly? Where?

Answer (score 3):

The following piece of code will try and fetch an URL. If possible (200) then 1, else 0 (404 or else).

### Code

```
/**
 * Count the number of urls that throw a 200 error or not
 * @param  {Array.Array} range data range
 * @param  {int} startcol The column of the range
 * @param  {int} startrow The first row of the range
 * @param {(boolean)} boolean optional, but defaults to true
 * @return The summation of the input range
 * @customfunction
 */
function imageCount(range, startcol, startrow, boolean) {
  boolean = typeof boolean == 'undefined' ? true : boolean;  
  var col_id = String.fromCharCode(64 + startcol), range_string = col_id + startrow;
  if(!!range == true) { 
    var endrow = startrow + range.length - 1;
    range_string = range_string + ":" + col_id + endrow; 
  }  
  var formulaRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(range_string);
  var sum = formulaRange.getFormulas().map ( function (formula) {
    return formula[0] ? formula[0].split(',')[0].split('(')[1].split('"')[1] : null;
  }).map ( function (url) {
    try {
      UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
      return 1;
    } catch(e) {
      return 0;
    }
  }).reduce ( function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }, 0);
  return boolean == true ? sum : (!!range == true ? range.length - sum : (sum === 1 ? 0 : 1));  
}
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Note

Paste this code into the script editor (*Tools > Script editor...*) and press the bug button to authenticate the script. After that, you are able the use the custom formula.